# SwiftUI computed var in custom init of a view error

Tags: swiftui, view, initialization, computed-properties

I want to be able to calculate a variable (nbwin) depending of the attribute "nom_rang1" of the coredata entity "RamiSession".
Basically, for each entity "RamiSession" whose attribute "nom_rang1" is equal to "nom_joueur_selec" (which is a String), I want to increment a counter and return the final value of that counter in the variable "nbwin". And then display it in a text box.

I think I have to compute that property "nbwin" in my custom init() method. But it doesn't work.

I have the error message on the line where nbwin is calculated in init saying "Function produces expected type 'Int'; did you mean to call it with '()'?"

But if I put () at the end of the calculation of "nbwin", I have an error message saying "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized"

So I guess I am doing something wrong...

Can anyone help me? Thank you

Here is my code

```
struct GraphView: View {

   
    @FetchRequest
    private var sessions: FetchedResults<RamiSession>
    
    private var nbwin : Int
    
    init(nom_joueur_selec: String) {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "nom_rang1= %@ OR nom_rang2= %@ ", nom_joueur_selec, nom_joueur_selec)
        let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\RamiSession.date)] // need something to sort by.
        _sessions = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: predicate)
        
        nbwin = {
            var nbwinTotal = 0
            for session in sessions {
                if session.nom_rang1 == nom_joueur_selec {
                    nbwinTotal += 1
                }
            }
            return nbwinTotal
        }
        
        
    }

    //
    var body: some View {

        Text("\(nbwin)")

    } // body
}
```

Comment: You are missing `()` after your closure. But, you probably shouldn’t be doing work like this in `init`

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx. But as I said, if I put () after my closure (at the end of the calculation of "nbwin"), I have an error message saying  « "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized" »

Comment: How about making it a computed property? Like I said, this shouldn’t be done in `init` anyway.

Comment: I am quite new in swiftui (and swift in general). But I am not sure I can make it a computed property of my entity « SessionRami », because I need to know the name of the player selected « nom_joueur_selec »

Comment: Store that in a variable so that you can use it later in the computed property